# __block in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

`__block` keyword on a variable in `Objective C` used to assure that this variable will be treated specially in `block`, but what is the equivalent to this keyword in `swift`?

I have done some google research but everything confuses me so far.

**Following is my code :**

```
var myArr = NSMutableArray()
completionBlock(myArray,nil)
```

I have tried

```
__block var myArr = NSMutableArray()
```

Comment: What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: What do you find yourself unable to do now that you can't use `__block`? What is the "special" that you're trying to achieve?

Comment: I'm parsing fetch result.

public func parseFetchResults(fetchResults: NSObject?, completionBlock: FbFetchParseCompletionBlock);

Answer (score 46, accepted):

There is no need for `__block` in Swift. A captured variable is automatically settable from within the closure.

Comment: `var bgTask = app.beginBackgroundTask {
            app.endBackgroundTask(bgTask)
            bgTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid
        }` I'm getting error with this line. **Error:** `Variable used within its own initial value`.

Comment: Oh solved this by adding one extra line `var bgTask: UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier = 0;`. Initializing the `bgTask` separately will solve this issue. But I'm now confused with `A captured variable is automatically settable from within the closure.` line. :|

Comment: Actually  'bgtask' variable was not accessible inside the completion block if i wrotw it in a single line as i commented above. I had the cofe for Objective-C in which it was working by using '__block' as prefix. So i was looking for the same thing ('__block') in Swift. But as I have solved this issue mentioned in my second comment. If its irrelevant i will delete my comments?